# How to create a multi task model that takes image as input and gives 2 images as output

Tags: tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation

I am building a custom model that has multiple outputs. I use a LinkNet architecture using a library segmentation_models. I am trying to build a multi output version of this model but the model does not train when I use the branched version that I built. Both the branches are the exact decoder section of the original model.

Code to reproduce: https://colab.research.google.com/gist/MitanshuShaBa/710dbdcf6cd9cc2621f9234200815210/linknet-branching.ipynb

Find a copy of this issue on keras repo issues: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/18268

I currently use unbranched model to generate masks of an image. I created the branched version to perform the same task for testing. Unbranched version compiles and trains correctly. When I perform testing on branched model it fails on the loss calculation.